# Cisco Anyconnect Company VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco

I am currently working remotely and logging into my machine in the office through Cisco AnyConnect VPN. I was wonder what information can the company see. For example, do they have access to my traffic when not logged into my office machine through the vpn. Can they see my original IP address and where I am working from etc?

Comment: Have a look around, this kind of question has been answered many times. The short version of the answer is that they can see whatever they would be able to see on a corporate controlled laptop connected to the internal network.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183834/personal-computer-work-vpn https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36686/once-vpn-is-unplugged-can-work-still-monitor https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177405/can-a-vpn-provider-mitm-my-ssl-traffic-without-me-noticing

Answer (score 0):

> do they have access to my traffic when not logged into my office machine through the vpn

If you are not connected through the company VPN they cannot see your full traffic. But if this is a company laptop they might still see later what sites you have visited by accessing the browser history and there might be software installed for more extensive logging.

> Can they see my original IP address and where I am working from etc?

The "original IP" is is the client endpoint of the VPN and they can definitely see it. From this IP they can roughly determine where you work from too.

Comment: Ok Nice Steffen thanks. What if I use a VPN and then connect through the company vpn to my remote machine. Would that slow down my ability to work on the ocompany machine?

Comment: @JonnyWilkinson: This is a different question. Please stick to your original one, this is not a discussion forum. Apart from that: the company might block this. And if this is a company managed laptop it does not change that they can still monitor what you are doing.